# How to integrate nvidia gpu with jupyter notebook for scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas

I know there are answers saying that tells how to integrate/use tensorflow or for deep learning libraries. I want to use it for classification or regression scikit-learn libraries. Is it possible. If yes then how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use GPU with scikit-learn as it does not officially supports GPU, as mentioned in its [FAQ](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#will-you-add-gpu-support).